# Can I make the <span> looks like a read-only and fixed size 's <input type="text" > using css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<span>` which encloses a very long message

```
<span>A very long message..........</span>
```

Can I make the span 's behavior look like a read-only and fixed sized `<input type="text">` using CSS or java script ? I want the displayed message will has the fixed length displayed and user can scroll to see the whole message if the message is so long, just like the input control of the following code:

```
<input type="text" value="A very long message.........." readonly="readonly" size="40" >
```

Comment: Why not just use the `<input>` tag sample you used?

Comment: Because the JSF tag only generate the  `<span>` , but I want the behavior looks like `<input> `.You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511280/format-the-date-using-fconvertdatetime-and-display-it-in-the-houtputtext

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
<div style="height:200px;overflow:auto;">text</div>
```

Comment: As here you should opt for div tags as these are inherently block elements. This will have vertical and horizontal scrolls enforced. You  can just have overflow:auto so scrolls only appear when needed. EDIT: saw you only have spans, in which case you will need to define, display:block in css.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used div because it is block element by default.

Answer (score 1):

Tadaa!

```
<input type="text" value="A very long message.........." readonly="readonly" size="40" >
```